# php search with pagination mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I have a search box where I search for products from different tables, the way I am doing this is with single query for each table because I need to link each result to a different page(when clicked on the result, for all the rows which came from `table1` I redirect to `table1detail`, the same thing for all the rest.).

The problem: as the list might become ridiculously long I needed a pagination and tried some from the net but most of them work with single query.

Does anyone know how can I achieve pagination with multiple queries?

This is what I am doing for all of my tables...then just getting the id on the second page and showing the details...

```
<?php 
$term = $_POST['searchterm'];
$stmt = $mydb->prepare(" SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE title LIKE ?;");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $term);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<a href='table1detail.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."</a>"
}
?>

<?php 
$stmt = $mydb->prepare(" SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE title LIKE ?;");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $term);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<a href='table2detail.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."</a>"
}
?>
```

Comment: likely best to use a javascript grid system fed by json data rather than server side pagination if need user to search all

Comment: @charlietfl could you show me just how, some kind of example?

Comment: maybe I'm not reading this right... is current interface just a search box? No data displayed until after search? If so might look at jQuery UI autocomplete. Are you familiar with `joins` also in queries?

Comment: yes no data is displayed until the user searches for a keyword. The search works fine and displays the results, I am stuck just on the pagination. What autocomplete has to do with pagination? I was told to use joins but they aren't helping me out.

Comment: I would send all the data back in json using AJAX and use a javascript paginator...lots of them around

Comment: @charlietfl this suggestion makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Why do you have multiple tables to search? what is the contents of these tables?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have multiple tables because I have different products, something like laptops, cellphones,...each has it's own table. That's why and the number of columns on each table isn't the same..the contents are just details about the product.